# Convert heights from DHDN Gauß Krüger Zone 4 to UTM 32 ETRS 89 in pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj, ellipsoid, vertical-transformation

I am using pyproj.

X/Y conversion is pretty straightforward through

```
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(31468, 25832,always_xy=True)
```

However, this does not transform the heights. 
From 
[Vertical Datum transformation using Pyproj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340392/vertical-datum-transformation-using-pyproj)
I got the impression that I might need to convert the heights with different CRS since the ones I am using are strict lateral.

I tried initializing the transformer with the corresponding codes for the ellipsoid systems

```
Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:6314","EPSG:6258")
```

But that throws

> Invalid projection: EPSG:6314: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)

I need help here.

Comment: I've never used PyProj, but you could define your CRS 6314 with `CRS.from_proj4` method (see https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/blob/master/docs/examples.rst). You can find proj4 definition for this CRS at Epsg.io site: https://epsg.io/6312

Comment: Are the heights ellipsoidal or orthometric/gravity-related? AKA DHHN2016 or 85 or 92?

Comment: They are ellipsoidal based in the old DHDN , aka EPSG 31468