# Converting Ellipsoidal height to Orthometric height in Python

Tags: python, pyproj

I would like to convert Ellipsoidal height to Orthometric height in Python. I tried below:

```
import pyproj


EGM2008height = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:3855") 
wgs84_ll = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:4326")
print(pyproj.transform(wgs84_ll, EGM2008height, 34.68016909181368, 38.31245226053967,100))
```

It gives this error:

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bos.py", line 26, in
> > <module>
> >     EGM2008height = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:3855")   File "C:\Users\abt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyproj\proj.py",
> > line 151, in __init__
> >     super().__init__(cstrencode(projstring.strip()))   File "pyproj\_proj.pyx", line 86, in pyproj._proj._Proj.__init__
> > pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: Invalid projection b'+vunits=m
> > +no_defs'.: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name)
> ```

I deleted 100 (as I use ellipsoidal height) and again same error. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical Datum transformation using Pyproj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340392/vertical-datum-transformation-using-pyproj)

Comment: In my question, i put code of the answer of previous question and it gave the error. The previous question does not have an answer

Comment: Which is your line 86? I use pyproj 1.9.5.1 and I have to add init to the EPSG string to work: wgs84_ll = pyproj.Proj(init="EPSG:4326"). There is no EPSG 3855 in my epsg file. Have you tried you transformation using cs2cs command line utility?

Comment: Thank for the reply.. Error in this line.. EGM2008height = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:3855").. But in EPSG website https://epsg.io/3855 there is.. I did not try the cs2cs because I dont know how to? Could you please tell me how can i do it in python?

Comment: epsg.io isn't the EPSG website for that you want www.epsg-registry.org/, but yes it exists as a valid code ~ http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3855

Answer (score 1):

Using pyproj 1.9.5.1 the following code works with and without elevation:

```
wdm = pyproj.Proj(init="EPSG:3857")
wgs = pyproj.Proj(init="EPSG:4326")
print(pyproj.transform(wgs, wm, 34.68016909181368, 38.31245226053967,100))
print(pyproj.transform(wgs, wm, 34.68016909181368, 38.31245226053967))
```

the result:

```
(3860578.7639253223, 4623659.355379215, 100.0)
(3860578.7639253223, 4623659.355379215)
```

I used EPSG:3857 because  EPSG:3855 is not in my epsg file.

Comment: My purpose is to convert ellipsoidal height to orthometric height. In the result, it is still 100. Thank you for your help Zoltan

Comment: As far as I see there is a shift grid in the definition of 3855 (the gtx file). You should give a transformation for the latitude/logitude (easting/northing) and for the height add geoidgrids="egm08_25.gtx" to the transformation. Of course you should download the gtx file.