# Why does pyproj give a different point location compared to ordnance survey when I convert from WGS84 to EPSG:27700 (BNG)

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, wgs84, pyproj, ordnance-survey

I get different results using 2 methods to convert co-ordinates from WGS84, epsg:4326 to BNG (British National Grid) epsg:27700. The differences in the plotted eastings and northings values are very small resulting in a difference of approximately 0.5m.

The main reason I am concerned is that when I plot the converted points in QGIS the results from using pyproj are in the same location as the non transformed points from WGS84. Converting the WGS84 points on the fly in QGIS plots the points in the same location as those I converted using the OS software.

I may need to use pyproj in the future and would like to ensure I have used the software correctly.

I am using pyproj and Grid InQuest II software from the Ordnance survey to run the conversions.

**WGS84 Co-ordinate set**

1. longitude = -3.209168460809744
2. Latitude = 55.950621342577172
3. Altitude = 116.378547668457031

**pyproj result and code**
x = 324588.97991822625 y = 673725.6892528223

```
trans1 = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:27700")
x1, y1, z1 = trans1.transform (lat, lon, alt)
print ("Transformer lon =   " +str(lon), " lat = " + str(lat) + " x = " + str(x1) + " y = " + str(y1))
```

**Ordnance Survey result**
Easting = 324589.0436663538 Northing = 673726.1910941075

**OS conversion validation**
I have 3 conversion methods from the Ordnance Survey Website

1. Grid InQuestII source code, used to create result above. https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers
2. Grid InQuestII software, a stand alone application, same co-ordinates but rounded to 2 decimal places
3. Online conversion page, same result to 3 decimal places. https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/gps/transformation/

The OS website and code converts from from ETRS89, epsg:4937, not WGS84, epsg:4326. I did try using epsg:4937 in pyproj and got the same result as using epsg:4326.

> OS comment on using ETRS89, EPSG:4937
>
> In Europe, ETRS89 is a precise version of the better known WGS84 (EPSG
> code 4326) coordinate reference system optimised for use in Europe;
> however, for most purposes it can be considered equivalent to WGS84.
> Specifically, the motion of the European continental plate is not
> apparent in ETRS89, which allows a fixed relationship to be
> established between this system and Ordnance Survey mapping coordinate
> systems.

**Rendering in QGIS**
I plotted a .geojson file with my original WGS84 lat, long values to see how that location compared with the converted values. I load 2 .csv files, one with the OS conversion and one with the pyproj conversion.

Method 1
Project Properties - Datum Transformations EPSG:4326 to EPSG:27700 selected

WGS84 points and OS points in same locations.
pyproj points about 0.5m apart

Method 2
Project Properties - Datum Transformations blank

WGS84 and pyproj points in same location
This was the confusing result, I would have accepted a result where the OS conversion was slightly different from the pyproj conversion and the plotting of the WGS84 result was in a slightly different location.

Added images of project reference system and project properties

[image: Project Reference system]

[image: Project Properties]

[image: full transform]

Comment: It looks a lot like a reference system issue. Can you add the proj definition (from the CRS selection dialog) of EPSG:27700 from qgis and/or from EPSG site? Any conversion on the reference axes is explicit there with the +to_wgs84 parameter

Comment: @Javier JC, Thanks. I suspect I have something in a setting somewhere. I have added 2 images. First is bottom RHS showing that epsg:27700 is selected and the other is the project properties for the CRS. This is the project that converts 'on the fly'

Comment: Can you copy the full datum tranformation, from +proj=pipeline ...,? It goes far to the right of the screen.

Comment: @Javier JC - Have added the full information.

Comment: I deleted my answer, it was not precise enough, you should see  the docs https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html and see how you can reproduce the transformation qgis is using.

Comment: Do you have the needed transformation grids installed? https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/transformation_grids.html

Comment: @snowman2 I thought I had installed the Grids, however I may not have installed them correctly. I will try to re-install.

Comment: @Javier JC will follow-up your link.

Comment: Many thanks Javier JC and @snowman2, it now works :-) The points are where they should be. I will write up an answer, but you were correct about the missing grid. The installation was different from the manual and I need to double check the final step I took.

Comment: The manual is for the unreleased version 3.0. But, it gives you the general idea of what you need to do. Glad to hear that it worked 

Comment: For other users reference, @snowman2 if the manual is for the unreleased version does that mean download_grids will be part of that release?

Comment: Yes, download_grids will be part of that release.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

This worked for epsg:4326 to epsg:27700 co-ordinate conversion. The instructions will be different for other systems but the principals will be the same.

Download the NTv2 grid information from the following web page, the second link is direct to the .zip.

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/OSTN15-NTv2.zip

Unzip to your data directory, the location I used was as follows :-

......Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyproj\proj_dir\share\proj

Pycharm and pyproj automatically finds the correct grid file and my coordinates now plot where I expect.

**The following 2 steps did not solve the problem**
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/transformation_grids.html#what-grids-to-download

```
tg.download_grids(verbose=True)
```

Gives the following error
AttributeError: 'TransformerGroup' object has no attribute 'download_grids

****NOTE - will be fixed in the next release so check the date ****

I could manually download the file uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif,  however the transformation did not work and when I tried to check the install with tg I got an error. (sorry I forgot to make a copy) I suspect I am missing a step here.

On the same page I had also tried the following 2 installs. They both suceeded but must be missing the NTv2 grid.

```
conda install -c conda-forge proj-data

conda install -c conda-forge proj-datumgrid-europe proj-datumgrid-north-america proj-datumgrid-oceania proj-datumgrid-world
```

Comment: I still get the following error: 'Transformation Inverse of OSGB 1936 to WGS 84 (9) + British National Grid is unavailable', and indeed the link only seems to include grids for ETRS89←→OSGB36, and none for WGS84?

Comment: Hi, assuming you are using QGIS, you also have to download the NTV2 grid information into QGIS. Download zip file from Ordnance Survey
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers.
Unzip and copy the files to C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj (or equivalent), there are other .gsb files there. I have another issue and there are some links to my sources there https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365132/qgis-3-10-not-recognising-projection-information-from-raster-created-using-gdal/365880#365880

Comment: I was using pyproj, and solved the issue, which was essentially that I needed to unzip the grids into the PROJ data directory at `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyproj/proj_dir/share/proj`, rather than `/usr/local/share/proj` (even though the latter was set with the `PROJ_DIR` environment variable, *and* set with `pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`...).

Comment: That's useful to know as I have to run a clean install sometime to solve my other problem.