# Convert Vertical Datum of GDAL file

Tags: gdal, wgs84, datum, egm96

I have 2 DTM datasets, the first has a vertical datum of `WGS84`, while the second has an orthometric vertical datum (*maybe* EGM96).  `gdalinfo` seems to only provide the horizontal datum info:

```
Size is 5551, 3250
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 16N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-87,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",32616]]
```

The output above is the exact same for both datasets.

I want to convert the second dataset's vertical datum to `WGS84` using `gdalwarp`, but I've tried many variations of the following commands to no avail (`egm96_15.gtx` is in `/usr/share/proj`):

```
gdalwarp in_dtm.tif out_wgs84_dtm.tif -s_srs EPSG:4326+5773 -t_srs EPSG:4979    
gdalwarp  in_dtm.tif out_wgs84_dtm.tif -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=/path/to/egm96_15.gtx" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_def"
```

I've also tried converting the WGS84 DTM to EGM96, but no matter what I try, the output file's elevations aren't any different from the input file. Multiple people have asked how to do this before, but none of the answers to other posts are working for me.

Why won't it work?

Possible issues:

- I'm using a DTM and not a DEM
- Versions: GDAL=3.3.2, PROJ=7.2
- Both datasets have the same `DATUM` tag, but store data in different reference frames

Comment: WGS84 ([EPSG:4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html)) does not care about the vertical dimension. How would you expect a transformation to occur on the z-dimension then? You can also have a look [there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391224/postgis-st-transform-seems-to-treat-the-vertical-datum-but-not-the-equivalent-py).

Comment: Hmmm...do you know why the first `gdalwarp` command in my post didn't work?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Questions with bullet lists of questions are likely to be closed as *needing more focus*.

Comment: Proj supports compound CRS with syntax 2Dcode + verticalcode `EPSG:4326+5773`. I think you are doing the right thing. Perhaps your Proj version cannot handle the conversion.

Comment: @Vince the bulleted questions are all in support of "Why won't it work?"

Comment: @Vince why is this question closed? The supporting questions clearly do not qualify as a list of different questions, they are just thoughts toward trying to solve the problem. I edited anyway even though there was no logical reason to close. Please reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax works for me with Proj version 8.1.1, at least the Z coordinates are changing.

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326+5773 -t_srs EPSG:4979
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
10 20 0
10 20 26.504430770874
```

What operation Proj is using can be checked with projinfo

```
projinfo -s EPSG:4326+5773 -t EPSG:4979

Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of WGS 84 to EGM96 height (1), 1 m, World.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=vgridshift +grids=us_nga_egm96_15.tif +multiplier=1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

WKT2:2019 string:
COORDINATEOPERATION["Inverse of WGS 84 to EGM96 height (1)",
    SOURCECRS[
        COMPOUNDCRS["WGS 84 + EGM96 height",
            GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                    ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                    AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                        ORDER[1],
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                        ORDER[2],
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
            VERTCRS["EGM96 height",
                VDATUM["EGM96 geoid"],
                CS[vertical,1],
                    AXIS["gravity-related height (H)",up,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            ID["EPSG",9707]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,3],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["ellipsoidal height (h)",up,
                    ORDER[3],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",4979]]],
    METHOD["PROJ-based operation method (approximate): +proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=vgridshift +grids=us_nga_egm96_15.tif +multiplier=1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1"],
    OPERATIONACCURACY[1],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    REMARK["For WGS 84 to EGM96 height (1) (EPSG:10084): Replaces WGS 84 to EGM84 height (1) (CT 15781). Replaced by WGS 84 to EGM2008 height (1) and (2) (CTs 3858-59).  For reversible alternative see WGS 84 to WGS 84 + EGM96 height (1) (CT 9708). An executable using spherical harmonics is also available."]]
```

Comment: Got missing grid error when running `projinfo`: `Grid us_nga_egm96_15.tif needed but not found on the system`.  This file exists in `/usr/share/proj`, and `projinfo` works when run from this directory. Do I need to add this to my PATH or something?

Comment: I have a `/usr/share/proj` containing lots of grids, and then a `/usr/local/share/proj` containing almost nothing. When I copy `us_nga_egm96_15.tif` to `/usr/local/share/proj`, the command works. How can I tell linux to look in `/usr/local/share/proj`?

Comment: What do you have as PROJ_LIB now https://proj.org/usage/environmentvars.html?

Comment: It isn't set to anything. I tried `export PROJ_LIB=/usr/share/proj`, but then `projinfo` command results in `ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db`. Seems like proj was installed to the local share folder, but the resource files installed to the root share folder

Comment: `export PROJ_LIB=/usr/share/proj:/usr/local/share/proj` seems to work. Is this reasonable, or did I mess something up in my installation of proj to have resource files in both the local and root share folders?

Comment: The `gdaltransform` and `projinfo` commands work, but `gdalwarp` still doesn't modify the file...

Comment: I am not sure if DTM can be handled that way with gdalwarp.  DTM is a raster file and I feel that it is 2D data, not 3D. You just happen to know that the pixel values of your DTM are related with heights, but what if the image was just a black and white aerial image, or RGB image? Perhaps there are some dedicated tools for managing DEM files. A workaround with GDAL utilities could be to convert DTM into vector data (3D points), perhaps through XYZ format, change the Z value, and then rasterize back with https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html by using the `-3d` option.

Comment: It seems that gdalwarp should be able to do that https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html `Starting with GDAL 2.2, if the SRS has an explicit vertical datum that points to a PROJ.4 geoidgrids, and the input dataset is a single band dataset, a vertical correction will be applied to the values of the dataset.` Ask help from the gdal-dev mailing list if you do not manage to make it work. See also https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-November/047762.html.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post if the mailing list helps me get it working. (I wish I had enough rep to upvote all your feedback)

Answer (score 1):

Use vDatum to convert between vertical datums.  vDatum is FOSS4G and multi-platform. There is a command line version for Windows users. [See this link](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/).

Comment: Tried to use on my file and it wouldn't process. Didn't get any errors, it was just stuck on 0% complete when trying to convert.

Comment: Can you make your data available

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot

Comment: I know VDATUM does points and lists of points.  Does it do raster and vector files too? ... Yes, the link says: Supported file format: text(ASCII), LiDAR(.LAS, *.LAZ) version 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.4 with Classification, ESRI ASCII Raster(.ASC), ESRI 3D shapefile, GeoTIFF (on Windows OS), and ERDAS IMAGINE (on Windows OS)