# Datum conversion from NAD27 + NGVD29 height (ftUS) to NAD27 + NAVD88 height (ftUS) using python

Tags: python, pyproj, noaa-vdatum

I am using Python pyproj to convert xyz values of Louisiana, USA region from `NAD27 + NGVD29 height (ftUS)` to `NAD27 + NAVD88 height (ftUS)`. So, I am not changing the horizontal projection (because it's `NAD27` for both), only the vertical projection is changing from `NGVD29` to `NAVD88`.However, `NAD83 + NAVD88 height (ftUS)` should also work because `NAD83` and `NAD27` are almost same.

here is a sample code for a point `(-89.8469444,31.23777778,2.73)` where input height is `2.73 ft`.

```
from pyproj import Transformer
from pyproj import CRS
#"epsg:7406" for NAD27 + NGVD29 height (ftUS)

t = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:7406", "epsg:8744", always_xy=True)#x is lon, y is lat
# t = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:5702", "epsg:6360", always_xy=True)# only z conversion
a=t.transform(-89.8469444,31.23777778,2.73)
print(a)
#CRS("epsg:8743") # Louisiana North
```

> output:

```
(3745443.9938408486, 998779.7596375213, 2.73)
```

So, the code gives me `2.73 ft` as output but the right result should be `2.267 ft`. Here is a [NOAA site](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/) where I can verify the output should be `2.267 ft`(just select `Horizontal+height`, `Geodetic lat-long` and `Orthometric tabs`, unit of height to `US Survey feet`). Here is another NOAA [Vdatum site](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/vdatumweb/vdatumweb?a=091701920221025) for the datum conversion which also gives me `2.267 ft`.

Comment: What happens if you replace and rename the pyproj GTX file with the appropriate GTX file from vDatum?   Does that alter the resulting values?

Comment: This answer seems relevant and can likely help you debug some more at least https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385738